Plasma Vault empty when opened
Upgraded Kubuntu 18.04 to 22.04 and during the process it said that encfs was now considered insecure but I elected to keep as the current vault is encrypted with it. Then when opening the vault after the upgrade was done it asked if I wanted to update the current vault to cryfs, so accepted that. Now when I open the vault it shows empty although the vault files are still there. Ideas on how to get it back? Note there is a cryfs.config file in the vault directory so presumably the upgrade to cryfs was successful?
To be clear: Had Kubuntu 18.04 and ran the dist upgrade command to go to 20.04 which then automatically suggested upgrade to 22.04, both upgrades ran without any error and everything else works fine apart from the vault coming up as empty when opened.
Update:
Using command line (/home/[user]/.local/share/plasma-vault/[Vault Name].enc) gives : Error 17 mount directory not found. However the vault directory (/home/[user]/Vaults exists and permissions look correct. Stumped!
Update 2:
Managed to get the command line decrypt to run but it fails with a 'couldn't load child blob' message. Searching on that and found someone with the same error going from Kubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and the fix is going to be to manually compile Cryfs after editing one file to ignore bad blobs. Apparently the change from encfs to cryfs is buggy. I'll do this on another system of course and have a spare laptop I can put Kubuntu 22.04 on to give it a shot. Will advise on outcome!

To be clear: Had Kubuntu 18.04 and ran the dist upgrade command to go to 20.04 which then automatically suggested upgrade to 22.04, both upgrades ran without any error and everything else works fine apart from the vault coming up as empty when opened.

Please edit the question and add this info not as a comment. Comments are where people trying to help you ask for more info,
